# Is there a way to use Eclipse external annotations on a class' generic parameters?

Tags: java, eclipse, null, annotations, external

I would like to annotate Vaadin's HasComponents class, which extends Iterable. I can annotate the iterator()-Method like this:

```
class com/vaadin/ui/HasComponents
iterator
 ()Ljava/util/Iterator<Lcom/vaadin/ui/Component;>;
 ()L1java/util/Iterator<L1com/vaadin/ui/Component;>;
```

so that I can iterate with a classic for-loop

```
for (Iterator<Component> it = content.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
  Component c = it.next();
  doSmoething(c);
}
```

but when I try a foreach-loop like

```
for(Component c : content) {
  doSomething(c);
}
```

I get a warning from Eclipse:

```
Null type safety (type annotations): The expression of type 'Component' needs unchecked conversion to conform to '@NonNull Component'
```

presumably because it should be

```
HasComponents extends Component, Iterable<@NonNull Component>
```

Is there any way to add this annotation via external annotations or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

If your ultimate goal is to have a short hand for the loop, and you are using Java 8 or newer, you can use forEach(..) with HasComponents in the following way using Streams and Lambda:

```
layout.forEach(component -> { ... do something with component ... });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same warning in the foreach Consumer as in the enhanced for loop